# How can I display the output of my userscript in a floating box on the side of the page?

Tags: javascript, button, greasemonkey, html

I'm working on a userscript for [Unicreatures](http://unicreatures.com/) that keeps track of events during exploration. It's working (well, it works but still needs some work lol) but I need a way to display the information I'm collecting that doesn't involve popup alerts for every step.

### How can I create a box on the page and display stuff in it?

I'm looking to create a frame, window, whatever on the left side of the menu on this page, and write the values of various variables into it as my script runs.

I'm collecting this data in localStorage, so my script will first update various localStorage properties and then display the results in this box somehow:

```
localStorage.steps = Number(localStorage.steps) + 1;
displayValueInFloatingBox(localStorage.steps + ' in Sargasso' );
```

I'd also like to add a button to this box to reset the values of these properties, so that I have a choice of keeping track forever or just for a session or two without having to edit the script every time (especially if I decide to share the script). I assume this would just set the variables to zero so I just need to know how to create the button and making it do something... This would probably use an eventListener somehow.

Please stick to plain JavaScript, no jQuery... I'm still barely getting JavaScript at the moment. And please, explain answers so I understand how something works - I don't just want code snippets that leave me coming back with a similar question because I don't understand why a bit of code was used.

#### Appendix A: my current script

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name Unicreatures Egg pop-up
// @namespace Unicreatures Egg pop-up
// @description Unicreatures Egg pop-up
// @include http://unicreatures.com/explore.php*
// @include http://www.unicreatures.com/explore.php*
// ==/UserScript==
var regexp = /You find an? (Exalted )?(.*?) egg nearby/;
var match = regexp.exec( document.body.innerHTML );
if ( match ) {
  if ( match[1] ) {
      alert( "Exalted egg found: " + match[2] );
  } else {
      alert( "Normal egg found: " + match[2] );
  }
}
var y = document.body.innerHTML;
var links = document.getElementsByTagName( 'a' );

for ( var i = 0; i < links.length; i++ ) {
var link = links[i];
if ( /area=sea(?!\&gather)/.test( link.href )) {
      link.addEventListener( 'click', function () {
      localStorage.steps=Number(localStorage.steps)+1
      // alert(localStorage.steps + ' in Sargasso' );
    }, true );
  }
}

//document.addEventListener('click', function(){alert('page clicked')}, true);

if(y.indexOf("You find a Noble")> 0)
{
  alert('Noble Egg Alert');
}

if(y.indexOf("You find an Exalted")> 0)
{
  localStorage.exaltedEggCount=Number(localStorage.exaltedEggCount)+1;
  alert('Exalted Egg Alert '+localStorage.exaltedEggCount);
}

if(y.indexOf("egg nearby!")> 0)
{
  localStorage.eggCount=Number(localStorage.eggCount)+1;

  alert('Egg Alert '+localStorage.eggCount);
}
```

Comment: 90% of the things you are asking to do through GreaseMonkey (Or UserScript) are exactly the same as one would do if making normal Javascript program that runs on the page.  Most of us here at StackOverflow don't mind helping someone who has made an effort, but we normally aren't willing to just hand over blocks of code.  Come back with specific examples of what you have tried.  I would *start* with just regular javascript on normal page. MUCH easier to test.  Converting it to a UserScript after is _normally_ fairly easy.

Comment: If you read my question better you would see I didn't just want a block of code. I was asking for help finding the answer, or if code was given I wanted to know what made it work so that I'd know how to do it elsewhere... and is it really that big of a block of code just to put a little sidebar on a page?  And code for a button considering all I need is to know how to put the button on there basically and where in that code to put my instructions? I didn't realize that it would take that much code just to make an empty  sidebar with 1 button and 1 checkbox so I could see how it was done

Comment: It doesn't take that much code at all, actually -- but and a little research will find you lots of examples on how to manipulate the DOM, add `div` elements and add or add a `checkbox`.  This question shows no attempt at basic research.

Comment: @KatCox Adding an element to the left-side of the page requires more work than it would to (say) add a 'header-bar' to the page. I'd suggest that you try that first. I'd just append a new div to the body - ensuring that it was the first element on the page. You could use document.insertBefore(newElement, document.childNodes[0]);, where newElement was created thusly document.createElement('div') document.childNodes[0] simply returns the first child of the document object. So, if you insert a new element before the first exiting element you'll have added your element to the very top of the page.

Comment: @enhzflep Thanks, now I know what to look up! I REALLY appreciate the helping hand... didn't really know I should be looking at divs, and for some reason didn't think to use insert in any of my searches (or the title of my question would have probably been clearer.  Now maybe my ADHD will let me forget about this long enough to go to sleep lol!  THANK YOU!  And if you add your comment as an answer I'll probably accept it.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Research only bears fruit if you know what to research.  My last search terms: 'greasemonkey display text in new frame on site'  That obviously wasn't going to bring up doms, divs or anything else that mattered.

Comment: @KatCox - No worries mate. The missus has ADHD. They've just put her on dexies and she's a new woman. I understand the different ways that I think compared to her - sometimes the smallest nudge in the right direction makes a world of difference. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's one simple way to add a box to the top left corner of the page.  First, we need to create a `div` element to serve as the box.  (Other HTML elements could work too, but `div` is a good choice since it has no special meaning, it's just a simple container.)

```javascript
var box = document.createElement( 'div' );
```

We'll give our box an ID, both so that we can find it later with `document.getElementsById()` and so that we can [style it with CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS):

```javascript
box.id = 'myAlertBox';
```

Now we need to style the box.  Since we're using GreaseMonkey, we can use [`GM_addStyle`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_addStyle) to add CSS style rules to the document:

```javascript
GM_addStyle( 
    ' #myAlertBox {             ' +
    '    background: white;     ' +
    '    border: 2px solid red; ' +
    '    padding: 4px;          ' +
    '    position: absolute;    ' +
    '    top: 8px; left: 8px;   ' +
    '    max-width: 400px;      ' +
    ' } '
);
```

Note the awkward syntax for including a [multi-line string](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Multi_Line_Strings) in JavaScript.  (There are other ways to style the box, too, which will work also outside GreaseMonkey.  I'll show some of the them below.)

Looking at the CSS style rule itself, the first three lines just say that our box should have a white background and a two pixels wide red border, and that there should be four pixels of padding between the border and the content.  All this just [makes it look like](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Getting_Started/Boxes) a typical simple alert box.

The following line says that our box should be [absolutely positioned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position) on the page — that is, always in a fixed position regardless of what else is on the page — and the one below that specifies the position we want to give it: here, four pixels from the top left corner of the page.  The last line just says that the box should not stretch to be more than 400 pixels wide, no matter how much content we stuff into it.

Speaking of which, of course we need to add some content too.  We can either just use plain text:

```javascript
box.textContent = "Here's some text! This is not HTML, so <3 is not a tag.";
```

or we can use HTML:

```javascript
box.innerHTML = "This <i>is</i> HTML, so &lt;3 needs to be escaped.";
```

Finally, we need to add the box to the page to make it show up:

```javascript
document.body.appendChild( box );
```

And there you go!  A box on the page.

---

OK, but how do we get rid of it?  Well, the simplest way would be to just make it disappear when clicked:

```javascript
box.addEventListener( 'click', function () {
    box.parentNode.removeChild( box );
}, true );
```

Alternatively, we could create a separate close button for the box and set the click handler only for that:

```javascript
var closeButton = document.createElement( 'div' );
closeButton.className = 'myCloseButton';
closeButton.textContent = 'X';

GM_addStyle( 
    ' .myCloseButton {           ' +
    '    background: #aaa;       ' +
    '    border: 1px solid #777; ' +
    '    padding: 1px;           ' +
    '    margin-left: 8px;       ' +
    '    float: right;           ' +
    '    cursor: pointer;        ' +
    ' } '
);

box.insertBefore( closeButton, box.firstChild );
closeButton.addEventListener( 'click', function () {
    box.parentNode.removeChild( box );
}, true );
```

Inserting the close button before any other content in the box, and giving it the style `float: right` makes it float to the top right corner and makes text flow around it.  The `cursor: pointer` rule makes the mouse cursor look like a hand when over the button, showing that it's clickable.

You can also add other buttons to the box (or elsewhere on the page) in the same way.
I gave the button a class name instead of an ID so that, if you want, you can give all your buttons the same class and they'll be style the same way.

It's also possible to just put the HTML code for the buttons in `box.innerHTML`, find the resulting elements e.g. with `box.getElementById()` and add the click handlers for them that way.

---

I said I'd mention other ways of styling elements.  One simple way is to just write the CSS rules directly into its `style` property:

```javascript
box.style.cssText =
    ' background: white;     ' +
    ' border: 2px solid red; ' +
    ' padding: 4px;          ' +
    ' position: absolute;    ' +
    ' top: 8px; left: 8px;   ' +
    ' max-width: 400px;      ' ;
```

(This way, we wouldn't even need to give the box an ID.)  It's also possible to set (and read) the styles one at a time:

```javascript
box.style.background = 'white';
box.style.border = '2px solid red';
box.style.padding = '4px';
box.style.position = 'absolute';
box.style.top = '8px';
box.style.left = '8px';
box.style.maxWidth = '400px';
```

You'll note that some of the names are different; for example, `max-width` would not be a valid JavaScript property name, so it becomes `maxWidth` instead.  The same rule works for other CSS property names with hyphens.

Still, I prefer `GM_addStyle` because it's more flexible.  For example, if you wanted to make all links inside your box red, you could just do:

```javascript
GM_addStyle( 
    ' #myAlertBox a {  ' +
    '    color: red;   ' +
    ' } '
);
```

---

By the way, here's a neat trick: if you replace `position: absolute` with `position: fixed`, then the box will not scroll along with the page — instead it'll stay fixed to the corner of your browser even if you scroll down.

Another tip: If you don't have [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) yet, install it.  It will make examining page content and debugging JavaScript *so* much easier.

Comment: God, I love your answers!  Very clear, very well explained, and plenty of reference links! Couple of questions... if I use `GM_addStyle` and leave certain values unset can I set them later in the script using the `box.style.**` format? I would assume yes, but coding rules don't always make sense.  According to the multi line string page you sent me to, your method of combining strings has the worst performance, so with bigger scripts for sure I should use a different method... they aren't really clear whether the `.join` method or the trailing backslash is the most efficient though?

Comment: I also just realized that I could probably use one of my webpage creation programs for this part if I wanted... but for something small like this it would probably be pointless. I used to have Firebug installed, but it did nasty things to my computer... firefox already hogs cpu and memory alot because of all my tab groups... they may have updated it since then so I might try it when I'm not stuck on dialup. I've just been using the web developer tools which seem to not be much use.

Comment: In your `GM_addStyle` you have `'` and on the greasepot wiki they use `"`. Is there a difference?

Comment: oops, forgot to accept the answer lol.  Anyways, I just found an alternative to Firebug and web developer tools for finding class, id and other stuff for pages that you might find interesting - http://westciv.com/xray/  you put a bookmarklet into firefox or IE and then click it on any page... COOL

Comment: You can certainly combine `GM_addStyle` and `.style`, but their interaction is not as simple as one might expect: `GM_addStyle` adds rules to the whole document's style sheet, while `.style` changes the "inline style" of a particular element. Basically, any style properties set with `.style` override those set with `GM_addStyle` (unless the latter are marked `!important` and the former aren't).

Comment: As for different ways of writing multi-line strings, the speed differences are almost certainly too small to measure unless the strings are _really_ long, so I just chose the way that seemed simplest to me. The trailing backslash method is probably fastest for long strings, but has the drawback that it can break mysteriously if there's any whitespace between the backslash and the end of the line.

Comment: As for single and double quoted strings, in JavaScript there's no difference except that (kind of obviously) a string must end with the same kind of quote as it began with. For more details, see e.g. [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#String_literals).

Comment: One more question that's kinda stupid but no matter what I try I can't figure it out (and research isn't helping). I wanted to have several fields with buttons under each one. Is there any way to have more than one `textContent` in a box or inserting buttons in the `textContent`, or am I stuck having all my buttons at the bottom or having multiple boxes?

Comment: You could, for example, create a `span` (or `p` or any other) element with `document.createElement()`, put the text inside it and add it to the box with `box.appendChild()`.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Thank you. I had searched for a little while and finally stumbled on the link you provided (after finally posting the question). I removed the comment then, but thank you for your prompt response. The `white-space: pre-wrap` did the trick.